# Win2k3 Terminal Services ErrorID 7024

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

We had an issue on a Win2K3 server yesterday where nobody could connect (not even from a console)  We only have the admin-mode terminal services enabled.  From a different PC on the same network, I checked Terminal Services and there was a list of RDP#xx sessions that had a status of "Down". Right-clicking any session and choosing "reset" generated an error:

> The requested operation cannot be completed because the Terminal Connection is currently busy processing a connect, disconnect, reset, or delete operation.

We ended up restarting the server to clear these sessions, but nobody could quite figure out how that problem occurred in the first place.

My current 'guess' is a problem we have with disconnected sessions.  For example, we have a user that leaves his work (vstudio/mssql studio/etc) open and just clicks the 'X' rather than logging off the RDP session.  There have been times when his disconnected sessions go 12 days before he logs back in.

Will these long-running disconnected sessions cause the error we were receiving that subsequently required a reboot?  Any other suggestions as to what would cause that fault?

Answer (score 1):

it's difficult to say for certain, but next time, try this:

Open a command prompt on your PC (*or anywhere where you're logged in with admin privileges on the remote system*) and type in **query user /server:***servername*

This will list all of the sessions on the server - and each will have an ID.  The console session always has an ID of 0 and the RDP sessions will be 1 and 2.

To kick one of these off, simply type **logoff** *ID number* and hit enter.  It should kick that session off.

It may not have helped, I get some success though, using this method.

You can obviously just try this out by logging yourself in somewhere, and running the commands to boot yourself out.

Comment: logoff ID number logged me off the local machine!